# How to make a Ruby gem executable

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I can use gems like RSpec or Rails or Pry by calling their respective gem names, e.g. `rspec`, `rails`, `pry` on the commandline. How can I achieve this with gems I create? I'm using bundler for the basic gem creation.

Comment: put your executables in bin/ folder inside your gem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually had my executable in the `/bin` folder.

Turns out my issue was that bundler's gem template is too smart for it's own good, and only includes files that have been committed to git. I hadn't actually committed the executable yet, so it wasn't picking it up:

```
# gemname.gemspec
gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($\)
```

Comment: FYI all you need to do is get it indexed with `git add` and then `bundle` again

Comment: Don't forget to make the file executable (`chmod +x bin/gemname`), and make sure the executables are added to your `gemspec` as well: `spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }`.

Comment: Since bundler 1.8 all application's executables should be located inside an *exe* folder instead of *bin*, so that *bin* folder only contains binstubs and development-only executables. Therefore the gemspec should have `spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }` and file executable with `chmod +x exe/gemname`

Answer (score 6):

[According to documentation](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) of Gemspec file you must put your executable in `bin/` folder.

Answer (score 4):

To make your gem executable in CLI, you should set the followings up.

1. Place your executable file the `bin` folder, like `bin/hello`
2. Make that executable by set permissions (`chmod u+x bin/hello`)
3. Set up gemspec configuration accordingly (`hello.gemspec`)

```ruby
spec.files  = `git ls-files -Z`.split("\x0")
spec.bindir = 'bin'
spec.executables << 'hello'
```

`spec.executables` considers `bin` as default folder for binaries and executables, though you can change it.

You can find documentation about this here: [Gemspec#executables](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables).